# How do I play Base64 Audio file in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How do I play base64 audio in Windows Phone, which methos is useful?
I am new in this application so forgive me and do not rate it as low.
See my code:

```
string mediafile = "asdgqqwerwe+azxhtoup";
byte[] PlayByte = Convert.FromBase64String(mediafile);  
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(PlayByte,0,PlayByte.Length);
MediaElement1.SetSource(stream);
```

I am getting error like this:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Stream must be of type
>   IsolatedStorageFileStream

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear. You need to supply IsolatedStorageFileStream instead of MemoryStream.

Comment: @goths thanks man, I know but can you guide me by a code please?I dont know..thnx